# Код на php.Где в этом коде ошибка?

Tags: php

Есть код на php для записи в базу данных:

При запуске на сервере выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса на строке 3.  Как  её определить?

```
include("Admin/set_connection.php");
    if ((isset($_POST['send'])&& if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text'](isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['ref']))){
    // Переменные с формы
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $reference = $_POST['ref'];
    $send = $_POST['send'];
    // Параметры для подключения
   
    
    try {
        // Подключение к базе данных
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_base", $db_user, $db_password);
        // Устанавливаем корректную кодировку
        $db->exec("set names utf8");
        // Собираем данные для запроса
        $data = array( 'name' => $name, 'text' => $text, 'date'=>$date,'ref'=>$reference ); 
        // Подготавливаем SQL-запрос
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $db_table (name, text) values (:name, :text)");
        // Выполняем запрос с данными
        $query->execute($data);
        // Запишим в переменую, что запрос отрабтал
        $result = true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Если есть ошибка соединения или выполнения запроса, выводим её
        print "Ошибка!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }
    
    if ($result) {
        echo "Успех. Информация занесена в базу данных";
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Вместе с ошибкой должно всегда выдаваться конкретное место, в котором она возникает

Comment: 3 строка. Конкретнее не скажу.

Comment: 3 строка в этом коде - комментарий.

Comment: if ((isset($_POST['send'])&& if <-- этот if надо убрать

Comment: У вас во второй строке `if ((isset($_POST['send']).....` какая то каша. Некорректный синтаксис. В этом и ошибка. Ее нужно переписать. Там внутри `if` у вас используется другой `if`, нехватает операторов `&&`, про скобки я вообще молчу....

Comment: А если попробовать вложенность, перебора не будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот корректный `if`:

```php
<?php
include("Admin/set_connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['send']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['ref'])) {
    // Переменные с формы
    //...
    //...
}?>
```

Comment: `isset`, кстати, может прининять несколько аргументов, можно написать `if (isset($a, $b,$c, $d)) {...}`

Comment: Дальше можно переименовать переменные и много чего ещё.